# Creating a mysql php link for the user to create a post in the forum

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a forum, following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kebwxI1Bw88. i've followed it succesfully up untill this point but for some reason the
 link for the user to go and create a forum post within a certain topic is not working. Can anyone see any problems with my code or spot any reason why this isnt working. i cant see anything wrong with my code and i have followed the tutorial to the letter.

The link is within the first if statement.

The link should appear on this page and the file create_topic.php hasnt been created yet.

```
 <?php session_start();?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Forum</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n6:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <header id="top">
    <h1>ITSize</h1>
    <nav id="mainnav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Fourth Page.html">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="Second Page.html">Revise</a></li>
        <li><a href="Forum.php">Forum</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <article id="main">
  <br>
  <br>
 <?php 
 include_once("DBconnect.php");
 $cid= $_GET['cid'];

 if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
     $logged= " | <a href='create_topic.php?cid=".$cid."'>Click here to create a topic</a>";
 }else{
     $logged = " | Please log in to create topics in this forum";
 }

 $sql = "SELECT id FROM categories WHERE id='".$cid."' LIMIT 1";
 $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 if (mysql_num_rows($res) ==1){
     $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE category_id='".$cid."' ORDER BY topic_reply_date DESC";
     $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
     if (mysql_num_rows($res2)>0){
         $topics .= "<table width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>";
         $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='3'<a href='Forum.php'>Return To Forum</a>".$logged."</td></tr>";
         $topics .= "<tr style='background-colour: #dddddd;'><td>Topic Title</td><td width='65' align='center'>Replies</td><td width='65' align='center'>Views</td</tr>";
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
         $tid = $row['id'];
         $title = $row['topic_title'];
         $views = $row['topic_views'];
         $date = $row['topic_date'];
         $creator =$row['topic_creator'];
         $topics .= "<tr><td><a href='view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid.">".$title."</a><spa class='post_info'>Posted by:".$creator." on ".$date."</span></td><td align='center'>0</td><td align='center'>".$views."</td></tr>";
         $topics .="<tr><td colspan='3'></td></tr>";
         }
     $topics .="</table>";
     }else{
         echo"<p> There are no topics in this category yet</p><br>";
     echo "<a href='Forum.php'>Return To Forum Page</a><br><br>";
     }
 }
 else{
     echo"<p> You are trying to view a category that does not exist</p><br>";
     echo "<a href='Forum.php'>Return To Forum Page</a><br><br>";

 }

 ?>

 </article>
  <aside id="sidebar">


</aside>
  <footer><a href="Third Page.html">My Account</a>
  </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us the file create_topic.php that the link is meant to lead to?

Comment: I havent created that file yet, the problem is that the link to the page doesnt even appear on this page but i dont understand why it its not appearing.

Comment: What is $logged returning? Are you sure you are setting the Session variable properly?

Comment: $logged is checking if the user is logged in or not. but thats not the problem the problem is that the link isnt even showing up on the page

Comment: The variable $logged should contain the link. Can you tell us its value after it has been set? (echo $logged;)

Comment: I added echo $logged; to my code but nothing was was returned when i built it

Comment: Oh my god, its working now. i knew it had to be something tiny like that that i had missed.